# SQL 3NF- Improving Table Structure

Tags: sql

I am trying to create an sql table stores business cases and business cases that are directly related. Right now I have the table below. The last column "relations" gives the id of the row it is related to.

| id | business | businessID | name | type | bus_date | relations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | S123 | Refund | CR | 2015 | 2 |
| 1 | sales | S123 | Refund | CR | 2015 | 3 |
| 2 | tax | T56 | Income | Tax | 2010 | 1 |
| 3 | Admin | A34 | Doc | HR | 1998 | 1 |

As you can see the first 2 rows have 2 relations, id 1 & 2. I think representing the data this way will make it very hard to scale the table when there are thousands of rows.

Are there any other ways I can split this table up so that it follows 3nf?

Comment: Please, no images (or links to them.) Use formatted text instead.